# How to update an existing instance in an ObservableMap with fetched JSON data

Tags: json, flutter, dart, mobx

Consider the following scenario:

- let's say, we want to write a book store app with mobx
- i have an ObservableMap in my book domain store to keep books keyed by their id
- regularly i pull updates on the books via api requests, these give back json objects representing a book
- to keep references intact, mobx recommends [updating existing instances](https://mobx.js.org/defining-data-stores.html#domain-stores)
- given the json it's easy to create a new book, but how do i merge this data into an existing instance (referenced in the existing map)?

Obvious solution would be to write the merge function myself, but this is not rly scalable, real-case apps often have a bunch of different models. Can you maybe point me to any good serialization frameworks, which provide such merge functions (besides the factory constructor and the export) or am i misunderstanding an important mobx concept?

Example code for the scenario:

book_model.dart

```dart
class Book = _Book with _$Book;

abstract class _Book with Store {
  final String id;

  @observable
  String title;

  _Book({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });
}
```

book_store.dart

```dart
class BookStore = _BookStore with _$BookStore;

abstract class _BookStore with Store {
  final BookService bookService;
  @observable
  final ObservableMap<String, Book> books;
  
  fetchPatients() async{
    final apiRes = await bookService.fetchBooks();
    // somehow merge the apiRes in the existing books map

    // DONT wanna do smth like this, as this would 
    // break existing references
    books = Map.fromIterable(
      apiRes.map((res)=>Book.fromJson(res)),
      key: (b) => b.id,
      calue: (b) => b,
    );

    // instead im looking for smth like this
    // which looks up matching keys and copies
    // values from the new book data to the
    // old one, and also adds / deletes 
    // new / removed keys from the old map
    joinDeep(books, Map.fromIterable(
      apiRes.map((res)=>Book.fromJson(res)),
      key: (b) => b.id,
      calue: (b) => b,
    ));
  }    
}
```

book_service.dart

```dart
class PatientService {
  static final exampleData = [];

  fetchBooks() async{
    //do something to fetch the books from the api
    final apiRes = await http.get(/*some url*/);
    return apiRes;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
books
  ..removeWhere((key, value) => !newBooks.containsKey(key))
  ..addAll(newBooks);
```

Comment: this does not update existing book instances, instead it deletes them from the map and adds new created instances (assuming `newBooks` are new created instances).